# On the average order of a multiplicative function defined in terms of particular values of Lambert $W$ function

Tags: reference-request, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, lambert-w, summation-method

We denote the main/principal branch of the Lambert $W$ function as $W(x)$, and we define the multiplicative function
$$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $n=1$} \\
\prod_{p\mid n}e^{-W(p^{e_p})}, & \text{if $n>1$ and has canonical representation $n=\prod_{p\mid n}p^{e_p}$}
\end{cases}.$$

Wikipedia has the article [*Lambert W function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) dedicated to this function, and a section dedicated to the canonical representation of a positive integer in the article *Fundamental theorem of arithmetic*.

I don't know if this function is in the literature, if this is the case please answer as a reference request my question, and I can to search and read these facts from the literature.

> **Question.** I would like to know if we can to state some relevant asymptotic for $$\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}f(n)$$
> as $x$ grows to $\infty$ (this is the approach to study certain arithmetic functions, see for example the introduction of chapter 3 *Averages of Arithmetical Function* from [1]). **Many thanks.**

That I wanted to ask with previous question is what about the size of our function $f(n)$, since it fluctuates it is better to take averages of particular values of $f(n)$. If my calculations were right, but these aren't adressing the question, I can to deduce that 1) *our function can be represented for integers* $n>1$ *as*
$$f(n)=\frac{1}{n}\left(\prod_{p\mid n}\log(p^{e_p})\right)\cdot e^{o(1)\omega(n)}\tag{1}$$
*where* $\omega(n)$ *denotes the prime omega function* $\sum_{p\mid n}1$, and 2) *that one has in Vinogradov notation that*
$$f(n)\ll n^{\delta-1}e^{o(1)\omega(n)}\tag{2}$$
*for each* $\delta>0$. Both statements deduced/inspired from formulas of the linked Wikipedia, if I'm right. From the representation $(1)$ we can deduce also an inequality $f(n)<\text{Bound}(n)$ invoking the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means, with $\text{Bound}(n)$ expressed, in particular, in terms of particular values of the prime omega function.

But I need a summation method and calculations to get an answer for the question, I don't know if previous calculations can be helpful.

**Remarks.** I doubt that previous multiplicative function has the applications that I had in mind (when I tried to evoke combinations of certain diophantine equations and an identity that involves $W(x)$ for reals $x>0$), but I think that to know a relevant/remarkable asymptotic identity for $\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}f(n)$ can be interesting.

### References:

[1] Tom M. Apostol, *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*, Springer (1976).

[2]  A. Hoorfar and M. Hassani, *Inequalities on the Lambert W Function and Hyperpower Function*, JIPAM, Volume 9, Issue 2, Article 51 (2008).

Comment: As aside question, if some user wants to add a comment about it I'm curious if this kind of *ad hoc definition* of a multiplicative function, **involving a special function** (in this post a branch of the Lambert $W$ function) is in the literature.

Comment: Have you considered an equivalent form
$f(n)=\tfrac1n\,\prod_{p\mid n}W(p^{e_p})$, for $n>1$,
which for prime $n$ is just $f(n)=\tfrac{W(n)}n$?

Comment: I believe that are equivalent forms @g.kov . Many thanks